# JUnit and JFileChoosers

Tags: java, junit, jfilechooser

I'm having issues with some test cases that make use of JFileChoosers. I'm looking for a way to programmatically get rid of file chooser windows (instead of pressing ESC 7 times) when running the JUnit tests.

I've tried to include the following in my test case:

```
Robot robot = new Robot();
robot.delay(1000);
robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ESCAPE);
```

This does not seem to work.
Do you have a suggestion?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Good question! Won't the robot work at all? Did you try putting it in a try/catch statement? That way you can monitor what's going wrong

Comment: I've tried putting it in a try/catch statement, but no catches. Also, if I set robot.delay(10000), I notice that the 10 seconds delay kick in **after** the file chooser has been dismissed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just a guess, but sounds like you're running the `Robot` on the same thread as you're launching the `JFileChooser`. If memory serves, a lot of the JFileChooser methods block the current thread until the user has selected a file.

Try launching the `Robot` in a separate thread if you aren't already.

EDIT:

For example:

```
// Start Robot in a new thread.
new Thread(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        Robot robot = new Robot();
        robot.delay(1000);
        robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ESCAPE);
    }
}).start();

// Launch JFileChooser.
jFileChooser.getSelectedFile();
```